# Can't locate @import "compass/reset"

Tags: reset, compass

I've been trying to locate **compass/reset** but I can only see **sass** and **stylesheets** directory in default compass installation.

I was wondering why screen.scss is having **@import "compass/reset";** since compass did not generate such directory.

Any ideas?

Cheers!